# Why isn't my UISlider animating?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISlider/setValue:animated:), it is possible to programmatically set the value of a UISlider with a smooth animation.  I'm attempting to do so from a custom view controller, the UI is being defined from a storyboard.

**The Context**

In my example I'm attempting to update the slider value from a custom view controller, the UI is being defined from a storyboard.  The example only renders a single slider.

When the user releases the slider, the value is reset to `0`.

**The Code**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var mySlider: UISlider!
    @IBAction func resetSlider() {
        mySlider.setValue(0, animated:true)
        NSLog("Reset!")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

`resetSlider` is linked to the `Touch Up Inside` event.

**The Problem**

When `resetSlider` is called the value does change on the interface, but it does not animate (the value simply "jumps" to 0).  My goal is to have the value gracefully shift back to zero.

Note: "Reset!" only displays once (per click), which indicates that `resetSlider` is not being called multiple times.

Why isn't this UISlider animating?

**The Video**

Since IB is so visual, [here is a video](https://vimeo.com/121498871) of the situation, *password is `code`*

Answer (score 53, accepted):

the setValue `animated` parameter doesn't actually perform an animation, but rather it *enables* animation.

To trigger the animation, you need to use [UIView.animateWithDuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:), and pass in the setValue command as the animation:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
  self.mySlider.setValue(0, animated:true)
})
```

**Swift 5**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
  self.mySlider.setValue(0, animated:true)
})
```

Comment: Great thought -- alas, according to my NSLog it is only being called once!

Comment: what if you use animation block (see edited answer)? there was issue with slider animation in early versions, not sure if that could be problem. Also, does it fail for both iOS 7 and iOS 8?

Comment: Sad that this got a downvote, since it does actually fix the problem. It appears that using `setValue:animated:` in the slider's IBAction doesn't animate, which is probably a UIKit bug.

Comment: This will soon be marked as the answer, but I'm proposing an edit to flesh it out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @Slifty is correct. But if you want UISlider is as smooth as defauft, so you can decrease the time animation to below 0.2. It may work such as 0.1/2 or 0.1/3.